# python implementation of c++ sort

Tags: python

```
    struct node {
        int L, R, i;
    }q[N];

    bool cmp(node x, node y) {
        if(x.L/BLOCK != y.L/BLOCK) {
            // different blocks, so sort by block.
            return x.L/BLOCK < y.L/BLOCK;
        }
        // same block, so sort by R value
        return x.R < y.R;
    }
sort(q, q + m, cmp);
```

where m is the size of q array.I want to know how to implement the above c++ code in python i.e compare on basis of function as third argument.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: what is x.L/BLOCK

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the proper way to write comparator as key in Python 3 for sorting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30565802/whats-the-proper-way-to-write-comparator-as-key-in-python-3-for-sorting)

Answer (score 1):

You're using a struct `q` to represent some data. I'm going to assume that you've create an object of the requisite type in python:

```
class Q: 
  def __init__(self, L, R, i):
    self.L = L
    self.R = R
    self.i = i
```

I'm also going to assume that you've defined `BLOCK` already, and that it's a constant.

So, given you have a list `q` of objects of type `Q`, you would sort that list by doing

```
q.sort(lambda x: (x.L/BLOCK, x.R))
```

that is, calling `sort()` with a lambda function which returns the 2-tuple for any given element of `q`. When a sorting key in python returns a tuple, the sort goes in priority order based on that tuple - if `x.L/BLOCK` is equal, only then does it proceed to using `x.R` for comparison.

Both `list.sort()` and the built-in function `sorted()` take an optional argument that is a function/lambda "key". This key outputs the criteria on which to sort, for any given element - similar to the third parameter of `std::sort` in C++, except it uses a key function instead of a comparator. In this case, that works just as well, though.

Comment: Most likely should be `//`, though.

Answer (score 0):

As of 3.0, Python no longer supports using `cmp` functions in its built-in sorting, only a `key` function that is expected to map the values to comparable keys.

Previously, you would use:

```
def cmp(x, y):
    if (x > y):
        return 1
    elif (x < y):
        return -1
    else:
        return 0

sorted([1,3,5,2,4,6], cmp=cmp)
```

If you don't have a `key` function available, but only a `cmp` function, Python has an adaptor function in the `functools` module:

```
from functools import cmp_to_key

def cmp(x, y):
    if (x > y):
        return 1
    elif (x < y):
        return -1
    else:
        return 0

sorted([1,3,5,2,4,6], key=cmp_to_key(cmp)
```

Comment: thankyou,It was the biggest trouble for me to code mo algorithm.